# Connect R to Athena with ODBC Driver on MacOS

Tags: r, odbc, amazon-athena, dbi

I'm trying to access data on Athena from R using ODBC.

I installed unixODBC via brew and the Simba Athena ODBC Driver from the web.

When I run :

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  Driver = "/Library/simba/athenaodbc/lib/libathenaodbc_sb64.dylib",
  S3OutputLocation = "",
  AwsRegion = Sys.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"),
  AuthenticationType = "IAM Credentials",
  UID = Sys.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
  PWD = Sys.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
)
```

I have this error :

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver
> Manager]Can't open lib
> '/Library/simba/athenaodbc/lib/libathenaodbc_sb64.dylib' : file not
> found

But this file exists for sure, why unixODBC can't find this file ?

I installed R and RStudio from the web and not via Homebrew, here is the sessionInfo :

```
version  R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
os       macOS Monterey 12.2
system   aarch64, darwin20
ui       RStudio
language (EN)
collate  en_US.UTF-8
ctype    en_US.UTF-8
tz       Europe/Paris
date     2022-04-08
rstudio  2022.02.0+443 Prairie Trillium (desktop)
pandoc   NA
```

Comment: @Julien_Navarre were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I might be off-base here, but I've always used `Driver=` in the instantiation call to be the *name* of a driver, not the location of a library for it. I am confident this is an ODBC thing, so doesn't matter if you're on macos or linux, or connection to SQL Server or MariaDB or another.

On a linux-box, for instance, in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`, I have the following section:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

When I connect to a SQL Server instance, my call is

```r
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server", ...)
```

The file does not need to be defined under `/etc/`, there are other ways to declare those driver segments.

Comment: A quick search yields https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-mac.html and https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-odbc-on-mac-os-x/ as two decent-looking links (I cannot vouch for all of their contents, offered as a starting point).